# Will i get ubuntu working with a gma3650 graphics card?

Tags: intel-graphics, ubuntu-netbook

Thinking of buying a netbook, will i get it working easily on a netbook with a n2800  chip and an intel gma 3650 graphics card?

Answer (score 1):

It works, but asks a lot of special configuration, and there is no openGL support, and you need it for unity effects...
I find netbook a bit slow reacting...
someone has made a ppa with the drivers you need:
https://launchpad.net/~sarvatt/+archive/cedarview
Better buy one with a AMD e450
joost van der wulp from belgium